# In polars how do I count unique rows cumulatively?

Tags: python-polars

My df:

```
data_string= """
A,B,C,D
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1
0,0,1,1
1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,1,1,0
"""
df = pl.read_csv(StringIO(data_string))
```

I want a cumulative count of unique rows (the 'actual' column at end of this). I try:

```
df=(df
.with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias("ones"))
.select([
    pl.all().exclude("ones"),
    pl.col("ones").cum_count().over(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).flatten().alias("cum_count")
]))
```

This is close but not quite (the 'expected' column at end of this). What am i missing?

```
# expected actual
#     1     1
#     1     1
#     1     1
#     1     1
#     2     1
#     3     2
#     1     1
#     2     2
#     1     1
#     1     1
```

Comment: your problem is that you have a bunch of whitespace. I edited it out of your example and then it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your example returns correct result for me, but you can also do it a bit more simple:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A":[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    "B":[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    "C":[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    "D":[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
})

df.with_columns(
    pl.int_range(1, pl.len() + 1).over('A', 'B', 'C', 'D').alias("cum_count")
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ cum_count │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64       │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 1         │
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 1         │
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1         │
│ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 1         │
│ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 2         │
│ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 3         │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 1         │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 2         │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 1         │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 1         │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Huh wonder why it doesn't work for me. Anyway that works great. TY!